# how to combine an integer and varchar field to construct an AJAX response struct in Coldfusion?

Tags: ajax, loops, coldfusion, struct

I have a query that returns integer in a column such as:

```
  1234.00
```

In Coldfusion8 I'm outputting this into a table and am adding another column with the currency like so:

```
   <td>#query.total# #query.currency#</td>
```

However, I now want to output the query into a datatables structure for which I have to combine both fields using

```
  <cfscript>
  variables.orderTotal = query.sum & "" & query.currency;
  QuerySetCell(rResult, "orderTotal", variables.orderTotal, variables.counter );
  </cfscript>
```

This doesn't work and breaks the whole script. I guess I can't "concat" an integer and a varchar like this.

**Question:**
If I want to output both fields into the same column, how can I do this then? I will loop over the query in the next step to create the AJAX response struct, like so:

```
<cfloop query="query">
    <cfset variables.count = variables.count + 1>[
      <cfloop list="#variables.fieldlist#" index="variables.i">
           "#query[variables.i][query.currentRow]#"
           <cfif variables.i is not listLast(variables.fieldlist)>, </cfif>
      </cfloop>]
      ...
```

Do I have to do it there then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. Did it in the loop construction the AJAX response like so:

```
 <cfif #variables.i# EQ "sum">
     "#query[variables.i][query.currentRow]# #rResult.currency#"
 <cfelse>
     "#query[variables.i][query.currentRow]#"
 </cfif>
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not you return another column in your query like:

```
SELECT  sum || "" || currency AS "total" 
FROM    xxx
```

Then you can use this new column total in your cfm code like this:

```
#query.total#
```

Comment: Always include your db type in the question tags, since SQL syntax is often db specific :)